# Docker on MacOS, receiving segmentation fault 11

Tags: docker, segmentation-fault, macos-high-sierra

I'm running macOS High Sierra on a Mid 2014 MacBook Pro. Installed Docker but when I try to run the `docker` command from the command prompt I get an immediate `Segmentation Fault: 11` error.

How do I debug this?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same Problem on Mac OS Big Sur Beta 10. I was able to get docker working by uninstalling virtualbox completely (Moving Virtualbox app to bin did not work).

Downloading [VB installer](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/VirtualBox-6.1.16-140961-OSX.dmg) and running uninstall_tool (bottom right on the installer), removed everything Virtualbox and Docker started fine

Answer (score 0):

Docker is server-client system so you should specify which is the cause of trouble, server or client, at first.

`docker info` is a way to check whether Docker server is running.

[The official document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/#check-whether-docker-is-running) says

> The operating-system independent way to check whether Docker is running is to ask Docker, using the docker info command.

Comment: Like I said, just running `docker` let alone `docker info` was throwing the error. I just reinstalled for a second time and now it seems be behaving

Comment: @JoshRusso I'm sorry I didn't understand 'docker' in "when I try to run docker from the command prompt" means `docker` command.